# Help with completing proof of cartesian products of two path connected spaces being path connected.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

I was wondering if somebody can help me with completing a proof of the claim made above. The problem I am having occurs at the end of the proof, so I don't want to bring it up over here without context. I would like to add that this is not homework for any class. I'm studying topology on my own for fun.

I apologise if you find that proving this claim instead of for arbitary cartesian products of path connected spaces is particularly reductive. I intend to prove that next. I just wanted to prove this as a lemma first in order to get a feel for the proof of the larger claim. Also, please let me know if you need to know any definitions.

With all of that out of the way, here is what I have thus far:

Recall: A space X is said to be path connected if every pair of points of X can be joined by a path in X.

Let X and Y be path connected topological spaces. Suppose they are non-empty, for the result is trivial otherwise. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be elements of X and let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be elements of Y. We are interested in showing that there is a path from $x_1$ x $y_1$ to $x_2$ x $y_2$. There exists a continuous map $f: [a,b] \rightarrow X$ of some closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ into X, such that $f(a) = x_1$ and $f(b) = x_2$ because X is path connected. There also exists a continuous map $g: [c,d] \rightarrow Y$ of some closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ into Y, such that $f(c) = y_1$ and $f(d) = y_2$ because Y is path connected.

Let $A = [a,b]$ x $[c,d]$. Define $f': A \rightarrow X$ by $f'(x) = f(\pi_1(x)) = f \circ \pi_1 (x)$ and $g': A \rightarrow Y$ by $g'(x) = g(\pi_2(x)) = g \circ \pi_2 (x)$.

Are these projections onto the first and second factors ($\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, respectively) continuous? We'll start with $\pi_1: $ X x Y $ \rightarrow X$, where X and Y are arbitrary topological spaces. Let U be open in X. We want to show that $\pi_1 ^{-1}(U)$ is open in X x Y. Notice that $\pi _ 1$ need not be injective, but it is certainly surjective. Notice that U x Y $\subset \pi _ 1^{-1}(U)$ is open in X x Y. Is it true that $\pi _1^{-1}(U) \subset$ U x Y? Fix u x v $\in \pi _ 1^{-1}(U)$. It is clear that $u \in U$, for if it wasn't, then $\pi _1 ($u x v$) \notin U$ (which cannot be). That $v \in Y$ is trivial. Hence, u x v $\in$ U x Y and $\pi _ 1^{-1}(U) \subset$ U x Y. Hence, $\pi _ 1^{-1}(U) = $ U x Y. We conclude that $\pi _ 1$ is continuous. Similarly, $\pi _2$ is continuous.

Knowing that, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we note that $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous by Theorem 18.2(c).

Let $h: A \rightarrow$ X x Y be given by the equation $h(a) = (f'(a),g'(a))$. We conclude that $h$ is continuous by Theorem 18.4 (Maps into products).

The problem I am having is whether or not [a,b] x [c,d] = [a x c, b x d]. This is needed to show that h is a path in X x Y.

This might be a particularly stupid thing to get caught up on, but I feel like I'm missing something here. I don't know what the order relation for the latter set is (I am aware, of course, that it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$). Is it the dictionary order relation?

If anybody has any comments on the proof (mistakes, improvements, etc), please let me know. I'm fairly new to higher-level math (I'm a physics student) as I have only had a year of exposure to rigorous math, so any criticism is greatly appreciated. :) Also, thanks in advance for the help!

Theorems:

Theorem 18.2(c): Let X,Y, and Z be topological spaces. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ are continuous, then the map $g \circ f: X \rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

Theorem 18.4 (Maps into products): Let $f: A \rightarrow$ X x Y be given by the equation $$f(a) = (f_1(a),f_2(1)).$$ Then $f$ is continuous iff the functions $f_1: A \rightarrow X$ and $f_2: A \rightarrow Y$ are continuous.

Comment: What's the point of confusing the issue with $a,b,c,d$? Why don't you just take $f:[0,1]\to X$ and $g:[0,1]\to Y$? And why would you want to define a function on $[a,b]\times[c,d]$? Why don't you just define $h:[0,1]\to X\times Y$ by $h(t)=(f(t),g(t))$? Also, why use the weird notation $x\times y$ for an element of $X\times Y$ instead of the normal $(x,y)$?

Comment: Hi bof! Why would I take f and g to be those two, though? X and Y are arbitrary path connected spaces. Perhaps if I provide the definition of a path in my book, things might be clearer. A path in a space X from x to y is a continuous map f: [a,b] --> X of some closed interval in the real line into X, such that f(a) = x and f(b) = y. I wanted these x and y to be entirely arbitrary, and consequently I can't choose what a and b are.  Perhaps I am missing something though. I don't want to define a function on that in and of itself. I chose A to a product of closed intervals and was hoping it

Comment: would equal a closed interval. I'm sorry about the notation being wierd. I don't know what all of the standard practices in topology are. That is merely what was used in my book (Munkres).

Comment: Actually, you **can** choose what $a$ and $b$ are. That';s why most books define a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$ as a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that $f(0)=x_1$ and $f(1)=x_2.$ Anyway, if $f:[a,b]\to X$ is a path from $x_1$ to $x_2,$ then so is $g:[0,1]\to X$ where $g(t)=f(a+t(b-a)).$

Comment: OK, how about this. Given paths $f:[a,b]\to X$ and $g:[c,d]\to Y,$ define a path $h:[0,1]\to X\times Y$ by setting $h(t)=f(a+t(b-a))\times g(c+t(d-c)).$

Comment: Oh, thank you for that! I had no idea. That's actually really cool!! :) I understand your first comment now. Your definition for h makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the other comment. I didn't see that I had to extend the chat. That makes sense too.

Comment: Sorry if I did not understand your argument, but one problem is that your map $h$ is defined not on an interval, but on a subset of the euclidean plane, so this does not give you a path in $X \times Y$.

Comment: No, that's an excellent point. Thank you for bringing it up! That was a huge mistake on my part. I'm not sure how I let that slip by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$ be two points in $X\times Y.$ Since $X$ is path-connected $X\times \{y\}$ is path connected (why?).So you have a path, say $f$ from  $(x,y)$ to $(z,y)$. 
By a similar argument, you have a path $g$ from $(z,y)$ to $(z,w)$ since $\{z\}\times Y$ is path connected. Concatenating $f$ and $g$ you get the required path.

Comment: Hi! Thanks your response! I'm not sure whether or not your question was rhetorical but here's my attempt:  Fix (x,y), (z,y) in X x {y}. There exists a path in X f: [a,b] --> X s.t. f(a) = x and f(b) = y by the path connectedness of X. Let g:[a,b] --> {y} be defined by g(t) = y. g is continuous by theorem 18.2 of Munkres (Let X,Y be topological spaces. If f: X --> Y maps all of X into the single point y0 of Y, then f is continuous). Then h:[a,b] --> X x {y} defined by h(t) = f(t) x g(t) is continuous by thm 18.4 (see theorems at the end of the question) and is a path.

Comment: Sorry, I meant f:[a,b] --> X s.t. f(a) = x and f(b) = z. My apologies.